# Send a mail with HTML formatting from TextBox

Tags: html, vba, email, outlook, rtf

I'm trying to mass mail from a mail base and a textbox, from Excel.

I create the mails with the right email addresses, subject and body. However, the body does not take into account the formatting used in the textbox. The formatting typically includes bullets, colors, bold characters (like in a Word document).

If I understand well, the part in the function `convert_RTF_to_HTML` looks at each character and converts it.

I used parts of code from https://codedocu.com/Office-365/Excel/Templates/Emails?2510

In column A I have name, in B the email address, C the subject and D the CC.

```vb
Sub MailAppelOffre()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("ZoneTexte 1").Text 'ZoneTexte 1 is TextBox 1
    
    i = 2
    'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        name = Cells(i, 1)
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        'replace place holders
        body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .To = email
            .cc = copy
            .subject = subject
            .body = body
            '.Attachments.Add ("")
            .Display
            '.Send
        End With
        
        'reset body text
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Edit : I tried to implement the part from codedocu below but didn't manage to run it successfully.

```vb
Sub GenMail()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varTeamname As Variant
    Dim varEmail As Variant
    Dim varBody As Variant
    Dim varSubject As Variant
    Dim strCopy As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    i = 2
    'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        varTeamname = Cells(i, 1) 'name of teams are in column 1
        varEmail = Cells(i, 2).Value 'email of teams are in column 2
        varSubject = Cells(i, 3).Value 'subject of mails are in column 3
        strCopy = Cells(i, 4).Value 'CC are in column 4
        
        varBody = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("ZoneTexte 1").text
        varBody = convert_RTF_to_HTML(varBody)
        varBody = Replace(varBody, "C1", name)
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .To = varEmail
             .CC = strCopy
             .subject = varSubject
             .HTMLBody = varBody
             .Display
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub


Public Function convert_RTF_to_HTML(ByVal parCharacters As Variant) As String

    '------< RTF in HTML Conversion >--------
    Dim sHTML As String
    sHTML = ""
    Dim bChange As Boolean
    
    Dim intColor As Long
    intColor = 0
    Dim intRed As Long, intGreen As Long, intBlue As Long
    
    Dim sFontName As String
    sFontName = ""
    Dim sFontSize As String
    sFontSize = ""
    Dim sUnderline As String
    sUnderline = ""
    
    Dim bBold As Integer
    bBold = 0
    
    '------< @Loop: Characters >------
    Dim varChar
    For Each varChar In parCharacters
        '----< Character >----
        bChange = False
        
        '< get Character >
        Dim char_Text As String
        char_Text = varChar.Text
        
        Dim char_FontName As String
        char_FontName = varChar.Font.name
        
        Dim char_FontSize As String
        char_FontSize = varChar.Font.Size
        
        Dim char_Underline As String
        char_Underline = varChar.Font.UnderlineStyle
        
        Dim char_RGB As Long
        char_RGB = varChar.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
        
        Dim char_Bold As Integer
        char_Bold = varChar.Font.Bold
        '</ get Character >
        
        '< Font >
        If Not sFontName Like char_FontName Then
            bChange = True
            sFontName = char_FontName
        End If
        '</ Font >
        
        '< FontSize >
        If Not sFontSize Like char_FontSize Then
            bChange = True
            sFontSize = char_FontSize
        End If
        '</ FontSize >
        
        '< Underline >
        If Not sUnderline Like char_Underline Then
            bChange = True
            sUnderline = char_Underline
        End If
        '</ Underline >
        
        '< Color >
        If Not intColor Like char_RGB Then
            bChange = True
            intColor = char_RGB
            intRed = (intColor And &HFF) \ 256 ^ 0      ' &HFF hexadecimal = 255 decimal
            intGreen = (intColor And &HFF00&) \ 256 ^ 1   ' &HFF00& hexadecimal = 65280 decimal
            intBlue = intColor \ 256 ^ 2
        End If
        '</ Color >
        
        '< Bold >
        If Not bBold Like char_Bold Then
            bChange = True
            bBold = char_Bold
        End If
        '</ Bold >
        
        '< Korrekturen >
        char_Text = Replace(char_Text, vbCrLf, "<br>")
        char_Text = Replace(char_Text, vbLf, "<br>")
        
        '</ Korrekturen >
        
        '< Formatierung HTML >
        If bChange Then
            sHTML = sHTML & "</span>"
            sHTML = sHTML & vbCrLf & "<span style="""
            sHTML = sHTML & " font-family:" & sFontName & ";"
            sHTML = sHTML & " font-size:" & sFontSize & "pt;"
            If Not sUnderline Like "0" Then
                sHTML = sHTML & " text-decoration:underline;"
            End If
            sHTML = sHTML & " color:rgb(" & intRed & "," & intGreen & "," & intBlue & ") ;"
            If bBold <> 0 Then
                sHTML = sHTML & " font-weight:font-weight: bold;"
            Else
                sHTML = sHTML & " font-weight:font-weight: normal;"
            End If
            sHTML = sHTML & """>"
        End If
        '</ Formatierung HTML >
        
        '< Text_anfuegen >
        sHTML = sHTML & char_Text
        '</ Text_anfuegen >
        '----</ Character >----
    Next
    '------</ @Loop: Characters >------
    '< Korrektur >
    sHTML = sHTML & "</span>"
    '</ Korrektur >
    '</ Text >
    
    convert_RTF_to_HTML = sHTML
    '------</ RTF in HTML umwandeln >--------
End Function
```

Comment: There is sth wrong with the code you provided in the question. Please read [ask] plus how to format code - and then update your question. (It is below `'------</ RTF in HTML umwandeln >--------` where it gets messy

Comment: Hello Ike, sorry about that, I edited my question so it's a little bit clearer where the situation is! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't use `convert_RTF_to_HTML` in your main sub `MailAppelOffre`

Comment: Yes, I usually fit it right after  Dim OutMail As Object and set body = sHTML but unfortunately the macro won't run then

Comment: What do you mean by "the macro won't run"?

Comment: Hello Ike, I editted with the full code above if it gives a better view of the challenge. I have the error code '438, I tried to dim body as String and Variant but it doesn't solve the error. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: At which code line do you get the error? Some hints regarding variable names: Don't use reserved words (e.g. name - that could lead to errors). Please dim all your variables _individually_ : `Dim name, email, body, subject, copy As String` (except of copy all variables are variant!) >> `Dim strName as string, strEmail as string, strBody as string, strCopy as string`

Comment: Hello Ike, I dimmed variables individually as well as took into account the Variant type. However, I still get Error '438! Is it maybe because the function that converts RTF to HTML needs a particular type of type? thanks! (I editted the code in original post if you wanna take a look)

Comment: I think this is the error: `ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("ZoneTexte 1")` --> at least you have to add `.text`

Comment: Hey Ike, added the .text (editted above also)! this time i get error 13 but i don't see where it doesn't match

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Hey, I get it in the RTF function, at the beginning of the '------< @Loop: Characters >------ part!

Comment: OK - now I got it (would have been easier if you had posted the error line earlier!): problem is, that textbox has no characters property which RTF function expects. Either you store the body text in a range (there you have range.characters) or you have to look for a different routine to migrate to HTML

Comment: Very sorry about that! So basically, I cannot use this function to transfer the content of a TextBox in Excel into a mail with the formatting? I was inspired by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXZeEmivn_E so i thought it was doable through the same way (I have the same problematic). Otherwise, maybe i could find a way to change the body of the text box so that the RTF function goes through? What do you think?

Comment: Actually, there is something I then don't understand. What kind of format is the body of the textbox in Excel if not RTF? If it is already HTML why doesn't it keep the formatting when put into the mail object? Maybe you can help me understand! thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry - I have never worked with textboxes ... so I don't know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your email code to be able to utilize the code/function from CodeDocu:

Lots of trial and error but I got it to work for me!

The Bold part doesn't seem to work for me though!

FIXED:

```
If bBold <> 0 Then
  sHTML = sHTML & " :font-weight: bold;"
```

```vb
.BodyFormat = 2 '* 1=Text olFormatPlain, 2=olFormatHTML, 3=olFormatRichText
    
varBody = convert_RTF_to_HTML(Sheets("Hidden Formulas").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters)
    
.HTMLBody = varBody '*.HTMLBody for HTML
```